# @font-face anti-aliasing in IE7-9

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to get @font-face looking perfect in IE, but am short of a solution.

I've checked out this:
http://allcreatives.net/2009/12/05/smoother-font-face-embedding-in-ie-7-8/
which didn't work on my Windows7 IE.

Anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sort of come to a conclusion that I feel confortable with.

For text that absolutely need to be perfect across browsers with the anti-aliasing, I would use Cufon/JavaScript solution. @font-face just doesn't compare in terms of rendering across browsers.

For text that does not need that kind of perfection and were using webfont Arial/Verdana etc. to begin with, I would sacrifice extra download of the font to get a nicer font right across the site.

So the answer to the question is no... it is not possible to force the browser in being able/unable to do anti-aliasing by front-end CSS methods.

Comment: I can confirm that the alleged [@font-face smoothing fix for IE](http://www.koodoz.com.au/klog/font-face-smoothing-in-internet-explorer/) does not work in IE6/7/8 and I couldn't find any other solution to make `@font-face` render nicely in IE6/7/8.