# Typeface.js: How do I know the name of the font I am adding?

Tags: html, css, sifr, cufon, typeface.js

I've converted some fonts using Typeface.js and the default font is working fine which is Century Gothic. But now I'm trying to use the Century Gothic Bold I uploaded and I don't know what the exact name is. I tried "Century Gothic Bold" but that didn't work. How do you know what the name is? The converter does not tell you or ask you to specify this during creation. Is it the filename?

I'm not going to upload any code as it's just a general question.

P.s. I should clarify that I know I can just add font-weight:bold but that would be the ordinary "Century Gothic" made bold rather than the "Century Gothic Bold" typeface which is a totally different thing. I already tried that and it looked terrible.

Answer (score 0):

@Adamantus Although not a specific technical answer, I have to say:

I used Typeface.js before as well. However, once web fonts gained traction and web font services emerged, I stopped using it. I was relieved.

To be honest with you, I think using Typeface.js is completely unnecessary by today's standards in every sense:

1. Too much overhead trying to make it work. That's why you're posting here after all.
2. Doing something with JavaScript that can very easily be done with CSS is the incorrect development approach.
3. If you're using Typeface.js is because you're using a licensed typeface (not font) and Century Gothic is not a free typeface. This means you are still incurring in illegal use of the typeface, only the technology is different.

My honest recommendation is to look for a web font that's similar to Century Gothic and then implement it with `@font-face`.

Here's a forum here in SO exactly for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675667/alternative-google-web-font-for-century-gothic

And here you can find a `@font-face` Sass mixin that can make implementing the web font even easier: https://gist.github.com/ricardozea/9029840

Here's that mixin:

```
//@include fontFace(fontName, 'path/to/font'); » No need to specify the file extension in the "fontName" value

@mixin fontFace($font-family, $file-path, $weight:normal, $style:normal) {
    @font-face {
        font-family:$font-family;
        src:url('#{$file-path}.eot');
        src:url('#{$file-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('#{$file-path}.woff') format('woff'),
            url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight:$weight;
        font-style:$style;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@include fontFace(muli, '../fonts/muli');
```

Good luck.

Comment: I used Cufon and sIFR as well. Those were the days :)

Comment: Prior to this site I used Cufon. I thought I would research to see if there was anything better. Google's service looked great but then it didn't have Century Gothic or the other font I needed either. I can't just use fontface because older browsers don't support it like ie6 right? I looked up sass and mixins. Not sure I have the time to delve into that right now. I would like someone to ask the question.

Comment: BTW, here's another forum here in SO about legacy IEs supporting `@font-face`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127409/do-ie-browsers-ie6-7-8-support-font-face